# iOS undo text field clear (x)

Tags: ios, ipad, text-input, undo-redo

Seemingly fairly regularly, I find myself clicking on the X in a circle to the right of a text field in an iOS app on my iPad, instead of just placing the cursor next to the final character in the text field. Extremely annoying.

Is there a global undo operation that I just can't find through google, or at least one for the factory provided "Clock" app, which I seem to have the most of this type of problem with?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The global undo guesture is to shake the device.

Answer (score 0):

There is a new undo gesture under iOS 13 which consists on double tapping with three fingers. Also, just tapping with three fingers shows a contextual menu that allows you to tap on an undo icon and other options.