# Is it possible to undo the last digit entered on my iPhone's calculator?

Tags: iphone

I use Apple's Calculator iPhone app all the time. Being human, I regularly make mistakes (or maybe my fingers are too big) and end up entering the wrong digit. But the iPhone’s “undo” function doesn’t work with the Calculator app. Is there any way to undo the last digit I’ve entered? Or do I have to clear everything and start again?

Comment: The iPhone has an "undo" function? how?

Comment: @Nzall here is the answer to[ undo](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/112452/120171)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**Yes**, there is an easy way to undo the last entry.

All you have to do is swipe the top of the calculator, in either direction. By ‘top’ I mean where the digits appear. This will clear the last digit you entered. If you swipe it again, then it’ll clear the next digit, and so on.

---

As a follow up, I agree there is some inconsistency here. I also agree with some of the comments below. Why it is I can shake my iPhone to undo something in other apps, but can’t do the same with the Calculator app, is beyond me. That said, I actually don’t like the whole *shake* function for undo. I’d much rather prefer a hard press on the screen (or some other input method) to be given the choice to undo. Basically I think it should be one of the options available in the same list as *cut*, *cop*, *paste* etc. If you happen to agree, you can [submit feedback to Apple](https://www.apple.com/feedback/iphone.html).

Comment: Well, even though can remove the last digit you accidentally entered, you can't actually undo anything. "Undo" would let you revert an action, say a multiplication, and would bring you back to the number you had before. Your answer certainly clears up OP's question, however :)

Comment: Indeed! There's no way to *undo* an operation and I've always wondered why they didn't implement the *shake* 'undo' function in the calculator for that purpose, although my preference would be for Apple to implement a totally different input method for 'undo'. I've never liked shaking the iPhone to do this.

Comment: In a calculator, it seems like shake should be the shortcut for Clear, not a single-digit undo.

Comment: @Barmar I like that idea actually. I've decided I'm going to submit some feedback to Apple on the whole 'undo' thing. I think they should change the way it works generally in iOS, and implement a shake for clearing the Calculator.

Comment: I doubt Apple would implement a shake to clear since there is already a C button to do that. Also, since one's finger is already there tapping the other buttons, IMO it just easier to tap C then shake the phone.

Comment: @user3439894 Haha, yep, you're right. :) I've just submitted some feedback that they consider changing their general 'undo' input method from a shake to a hard and/or long press, and that undo appears as one of the options alongside cut, copy, paste, etc. IMHO that would improve the user experience.