# Can you still ’undo’ on the iPhone in iOS 11?

Tags: iphone, ios, undo-redo

I found this question and answer [iOS undo text field clear (x)](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/112438/168832) via a Google search. Thing is, when I shake my iPhone nothing happens.

Can you still undo on an iPhone using iOS 11? How do I use it?

I didn’t see anything about Undo in settings!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes!**

On your iPhone do as follows:

1. Open Settings
2. Tap on General > Accessibility
3. Swipe up until you see the *Shake to Undo* option
4. Tap on this and enable it
5. Exit Settings